# Pagination in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create pagination in laravel but its not working.

Here's the code :

```
$result=DB::table('sample')
            ->select()
            ->where('id','=',1)->orWhere('id','=',2)
            ->get()->paginate(10);
        return $result;
```

Comment: It's always nice to read the actual documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$result=DB::table('sample')
            ->select()
            ->where('id','=',1)->orWhere('id','=',2)
            ->paginate(10);
        return $result;
```

Paginate will not work with get

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `get()` or `paginate()` methods, you will get a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections#introduction) instead of Eloquent object.

> All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are instances of the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object, including results retrieved via the `get` method or accessed via a relationship.

When you're chaining `get()->paginate()`, you're trying to use `paginate()` method on a collection which will never work.

So, just use it without `get()`:

```
$result = DB::table('sample')
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->orWhere('id', 2)
            ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

why you are using get() with pagination, remove this and write your query as

```
$result=DB::table('sample')
        ->select()
        ->where('id','=',1)->orWhere('id','=',2)
        ->paginate(10);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pagination in laravel**

**make sure this in controller**

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

**in service provider **

```
paginator::sseBootstrap();
```

[image]

[image]

 
[image]